# Android - Refresh/restart a previous activity

Tags: android, database, android-activity, refresh, restart

When a user returns from an activity to the main menu of my program, what class do you use to for example; refresh/restart the main menu (update it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends... if you started the second activity and want to update the first, you should:

- Use `startActivityForResult` method to start the second activity
- Place the "refresh code" in the `onActivityResult` method of your first activity.

If that's not the scenario, you can try to place the refresh code in `onResume`.

Comment: Manage to work it out, not sure if this is the right way to do it but it gives the same result:

(Added this to the second activity)
 
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  this.startActivity(new Intent(<Location>.this, <Destination>.class));
 }

Is this method acceptable?

Comment: (By the way I figured it out before you posted, I am just wondering whether to re-do it all or not.)

Comment: If you want my opinion, that way smells. It may work, but that's not the Android way.

Comment: startActivityForResult bit works but the onActivityResult bit doesn't, it doesn't run the refresh code, I tried the onActivityResult method on both the first and second activity and it did nothing.

Comment: Got it to work, here is the working code for onActivityResult, thank you by the way :D : protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode==<chosen code number>) {
   this.startActivity(new Intent(<location>.this, <destination>.class));
  }
 }